# How I can set a date string from twitter to a NSDATE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, datetime, formatting

The date you get back from twitter is in this format `Fri Aug 07 12:40:04 +0000 2009`. I am able to assign the value to a NSDate without issue. However, when I attempt to use NSDateFormatter, I get a nil returned to me. What am I missing?

```
    NSDate *createdAt = [messageData objectForKey:@"created_at"];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"M/d/yy HH:mm"];

    NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:createdAt];


    label.text = dateString;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the object associated with the @"created_at" key is a valid NSDate object, this code should work.

However, I'm guessing that it is actually an NSString.  If so, it will produce the behavior you're describing.

If I'm right, the code snippet above is assigning an NSString object to an NSDate reference.  NSDictionary returns untyped 'id' objects, so the compiler won't give you a type mismatch warning.

You'll have to use NSDateFormatter to parse the string into an NSDate (see dateFromString:).

Answer (score 11):

i had the same question, and i could not resolve it with the current above answers.  so here is what worked for me:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    //Wed Dec 01 17:08:03 +0000 2010
    [df setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:[[tweets objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: TWITTER_CREATED_AT_JSON_KEY]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd yyyy"];
    NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

where `tweets` is an `NSMutableArray` filled with `NSDictionary` objects, `storyIndex` being the row int value (in the tableview), and `TWITTER_CREATED_AT_JSON_KEY` being a constant `NSString` with value `created_at`.  use the `dateStr` wherever you wish to display the date

Comment: Thanks @binnyb. Twitter have changed the format now to "Wed, 28 Dec 2011 16:48:59 +0000", so the first format should be: [df setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"].

Comment: It seems that Twitter have changed the format again, to `@"eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"` (or 'Tue Feb 08 15:54:03 +0000 2011')

Answer (score 3):

It looks likes, Twitter changes the format again and again. These works for me now. Don't forget to set the locale.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
//Mon, 29 Oct 2012 12:24:50 +0000
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
[df setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:[element valueForKey:@"created_at"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

`[element valueForKey:@"created_at"]` - date from twitter

Answer (score 0):

Above nothing worked for me - try this for Twitter: (I've also included a nice [nsdate category](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo) for better showing date

```
lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:16];
        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        //"created_at": "Tue Jul 09 07:45:01 +0000 2013",
        [df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"];
        NSTimeInterval timeIntveral = [[df dateFromString:[[_twitterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"created_at"]] timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeIntveral];

        //will work if you added the nsdate category, linked above
        NSString *ago = [date timeAgo];
        NSLog(@"Output is: \"%@\" %.f", ago,timeIntveral);
        lbl.text = ago;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: any reason why are you using timeIntervalSince1970? Can't you just assign result of the dateFromString: to your date variable?

Answer (score -1):

First off, what are you using `stringFromDate:` for? That's if you already have an NSDate and want to make a string representing it.

Moreover, when you do use the date formatter, you're giving it a format string that doesn't match the date string you're trying to interpret.

Change the format string to match your date strings, and use `dateFromString:` instead of `stringFromDate:` (with the attendant changes to your variable declarations), and it should work.